# Фиксированное меню (position fixed) - пропадает горизонтальный скроллинг

Tags: html, css

Задача. 
Фиксированное меню вверху страницы шириной от 1024px до 1680px. Должно выравниваться по центру, иметь декоративный border снизу и отступы по краям.

Проблема.
При уменьшении окна браузера до ширины менее чем 1024px не появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки, что делает невозможным использование такой навигации на экранах c шириной менее 1024px.

Эта же проблема присутствует на сайте http://www.nike.com/us/en_us/ но у этого ресурса имеется отдельная мобильная версия сайта что, собственно, и нивелирует этот недостаток.

Разметка:

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Downloads</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Applications</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Projects</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
```

Стили:

```
body, 
html 
{ 
font-size: 100%;    
padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before 
{
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

li 
{
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 2em;
}

.header 
{
background: DarkSalmon;
padding: 0 3em;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.navigation 
{
border: 5px solid IndianRed;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: right;
min-width: 1024px;
max-width: 1680px;
}

.content
{
background: MediumSeaGreen;
height: 4000px;
}
```

Comment: какой результат вы хотите?

Comment: как вариант для разрешения менее чем 1024px - прятать меню и показывать Hamburger Icon

Comment: Дело в том, что сайт технический, и не предполагает адаптивных стилей. Только десктопная версия.

Comment: вот и пример сделал - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/9e1p1a7c/

Comment: Ну так можно было бы сделать, но весь основной контент - это длинные таблицы с техническими данными, которые нет смысла делать адаптивными.

Comment: мне кажется пример с jsfiddle - такой громоздкий код - проще на jquery сделать - в 4 строки

Answer (score 1):

во-первых, нужно установить классу `header` что он может показывать скролл, например, чтобы показывался только горизонтальный скролл, когда содержимое больше контейнера, нужно добавить

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

Далее нужно убрать *padding*

```
padding: 0;
```

и добавить позицию слева

```
left: 0;
```

Пример:

```css
body { margin: 0;}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
.header {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-x: auto;
  top: 50px; //изменено только для демонстрации
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.navigation {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 1024px;
  max-width: 1680px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Downloads</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Applications</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** похоже что реализовать *что бы при ресайзе появлялся общий скроллбар для всей страницы внизу окна браузера* с `position:fixed` - не получится.

В качестве обходного решения: выставить классу `header`: `position:absolute` и подписавшись на события скрола менять ему свойство *top*

например с помощью jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.header').css('top', $(this).scrollTop() + "px");
})
```

Пример:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.header').css('top', $(this).scrollTop() + "px");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
.header {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px; //изменено только для демонстрации
}
.navigation {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 1024px;
  max-width: 1680px;
}
.placeholder {
  height: 1024px;
  content: "."
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Downloads</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Applications</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="placeholder">&nbsp;</div>
```

**UPD** пример с разметкой из поста.

- вместо fixed - absolute
- min-width - перенесен в header, а так же добавлен в content

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.header').css('top', $(this).scrollTop() + "px");
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.header {
  background: DarkSalmon;
  padding: 0 3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
}

.navigation {
  border: 5px solid IndianRed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 1680px;
}

.content {
  background: MediumSeaGreen;
  height: 4000px;
  min-width: 1024px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Downloads</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Applications</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: Такая конструкция точно не подходит, так как содержит дополнительный скроллбар. Я хотел добиться того, что бы при ресайзе появлялся общий скроллбар для всей страницы внизу окна браузера

Comment: @DIV1000, тогда добавьте это в пост, в остальном решение вас устраивало бы?

Comment: @DIV1000, обновил ответ

Comment: Идея интересная, но из-за постоянного пересчета значений 'top' дергается меню. Я посмотрел на англ. сайте и нашел это:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846807/issue-with-fixed-header-no-horizontal-scroll     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291226/fix-header-to-top-of-page-with-horizontal-scroll/12291301#12291301  Получается, что так как Вы и сказали - вопрос решается только при помощи js

Comment: @DIV1000, не совсем понял почему дергается? в приведенном примере в ответе вроде не дергается

Comment: Я обновил код. Попробуйте его использовать. Это то, что мне нужно в итоговом варианте, ну и естественно что бы была полоса гориз. прокрутки, которая отобразит все пункты меню и правый отступ. И еще хотел отметить, что при комбинации ctrl - макет должен уменьшаться с выравниванием по центру, а не съезжать в сторону.

Comment: @DIV1000, вы можете все это в сам вопрос добавить? а то получается - один вариант есть - оказывается хотели по другому, второй вариант - а оказывается хотели что-то еще кроме прокрутки

Comment: @DIV1000, обновил ответ